# HOG Trilinear Interpolation of Histogram Bins clarification

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, histogram

Like others before me [HOG Trilinear Interpolation of Histogram Bins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565412/hog-trilinear-interpolation-of-histogram-bins) I am trying to understand and implement trilinear interpolation for HoG. Dalal's Thesis' here:

http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/dalal/NavneetDalalThesis.pdf

The issue I am struggling to understand is that as I understand it, the task is of value re-destribution into bins rather than interpolation of known bin values. 
I am clear about the one dimensional case in the orientation dimension;

for example if I have a known pixel gradient orientation value of `75` and nearest bins of `z1=60` and `z2=80` (bin step size `b=20`), then the pixel value (gradient magnitude in this case, say `w=16`) will be distributed at a ratio of `1:3` into the adjacent bins (4 into the `60` bin and `12` into the `80` bin) right?

When it comes to the three dimensional case that requires spatial interpolation of the magnitude, I'm stumped. I fail to understand how the magnitude is redestributed to the appropriate bins.
Any clear explanation for someone, who is admitedly slow, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Histogram of Oriented Gradients as discussed by Navneet Dalal, discusses interpolation of the gradient magnitudes of the cells into orientation bins ( for 0 to 180 degrees we have 9 bins with a bin step size or bandwidth of 20 degrees)

A naive approach would be to just do this for every cell in the window/image but this would result in aliasing effects. In order to reduce aliasing it is discussed that the image should be partitioned into blocks (preferably overlapping) of n x n cells.
eg. for a 64 x 128 pixel image you could define the following:
1. Cell Size = 8x8 pixels
2. Block Size = 2x2 cells

this gives:
 
8x16 cells, or 
4x8 **NON-overlapping** block's or 
7x15 Blocks with a stride of 8 i.e 7x15 **50% overlapping blocks**

So instead of performing linear histogram interpolation of every cell on its own you would perform Trilinear interpoloation of cells in blocks i.e Interpolated trilinearly:
 - Bilinearly into spatial cells (of the block)
 - Linearly into orientation bins

Visualization of HoG Trilinear interpolation :
http://www.ultraimg.com/d7km