# soft binning in SIFT

Tags: opencv, image-processing, sift

According to "Lowe, David G. "Distinctive image features from scale-invariant keypoints." International journal of
computer vision 60.2 (2004): 91-110 "

> "It is important to avoid all boundary affects in which the descriptor
>   abruptly changes as a sample shifts smoothly from being within one
>   histogram to another or from one orientation to another. Therefore,
>   trilinear interpolation is used to distribute the value of each
>   gradient sample into adjacent histogram bins. In other words, each
>   entry into a bin is multiplied by a weight of 1−d for each dimension,
>   where d is the distance of the sample from the central value of the
>   bin as measured in units of the histogram bin spacing."

I am calculating the orientation[t] and location of gradient(x,y) which will be in floating point. Currently, I was just
providing the gradient magnitude to 3d histogram values[t][x][y] ( means the lower bound of floating point values of t,x
and y). But, according to paper, I have to distribute the gradient magnitude to adjacent bins. I am not sure about how
to distribute it.

I got my answer on following link:
[HOG Trilinear Interpolation of Histogram Bins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565412/hog-trilinear-interpolation-of-histogram-bins)

Comment: so your question is how trilinear interpolation works? I'll explain it in one dimension (linear interpolation), for 2 dimensions it works "in the same way" (it just looks more comlicated). You have values at discrete positions `[t]` but you want to compute the value at continuous values like `[t+0.33]` (between `t` and `t+1`). Just take the combination `0.67*[t] and 0.33*[t+1]. For 3D look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation#Method

Comment: @Micka, Actually here, I have value available at the continuous position and I want to divide it into discrete positions.

Comment: ok... so if you have for example the value at `[t+0.33]` and at `[t-0.5]` you want to compute the value at `[t]` which should be `0.5/0.83*[t+0.33] + 0.33/0.83*[t-0.5]`?!?