# Not sure what this 'histogram code' is doing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, histogram, matlab-cvst, quantization

I have following code that was given to me, but I am not sure at all as to what the logic here is. The idea, I believe, is that this will histogram/quantize my data. Here is the code:

The input:

```
x = 180.*rand(1,1000); %1000 points from 0 to 180 degrees.
binWidth = 20;         %I want the binWidth to be 20 degrees.
```

The main function:

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Compute the closest bin center x1 that is less than or equal to x
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------

function [x1, b1] = computeLowerHistBin(x, binWidth)

% Bin index
bin = floor(x./binWidth - 0.5);

% Bin center x1
x1 = binWidth * (bin + 0.5);

% add 2 to get to 1-based indexing
b1 = bin + 2;
end
```

Finally, the final 'quantized' data:

```
w = 1 - (x - x1)./binWidth
```

Here is what I do not get: I do not understand - at all - just why exactly `x1` is computed the way it is, and also why/how `w` is computed the way it is. In fact, of all the things, `w` confuses me the most. I literally cannot understand the logic here, or what is really intended. Would appreciate a detailed elucidation of this logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

He is binning with `lb <= x < up` and splitting the interval `[0,180]` in `[-10,10), [10, 30), [30,40) ..., [150,170), [170,190)`.

Suppose `x = 180`, then:

```
bin = floor(180/20-0.5) = floor(9-0.5) = floor(8.5) = 8;
```

while if `x = 0`:

```
bin = floor(`0/20-0.5) = floor(-0.5) = floor(-1) = -1;
```

which respectively translate into `x1 = 20 * (8+0.5) = 170` and `x1 = -10` which seems like what the function suggests `lowerHistBin()`.

In the end, `w` simply measures how far the point `x` is from the corresponding lower bin `x1`. Notice that `w` is in (0,1], with `w` being 1 when `x = x1` and approaching 0 when `x -> x1+binWidth`. So, if x say approaches 170, then `w` will approach `1 - (170-150)/20 = 0`.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. So, a couple things... I) Why - or how - on Earth does a measure of the distance to the lower bin x1, mean anything useful? To be clear, he is using it in this context [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344764/not-getting-what-spatial-weights-for-hog-are/26346802?noredirect=1#comment41356464_26346802). II) Going back to `x1` - I do not understand why, when given a data that is bounded from 0 to 180, he basically makes the first histogram starting from [-10 10), [10 30), etc. Why not go [0 20), [20 40), etc? Doesnt that make more sense? Many thanks!!

Comment: Also I think what you have written as far as `w` is inverted. It gets closer to 1, the closer the number is to the left edge.

Comment: @Learnaholic correct about `w` will amend, was too tired :). I have no idea why he does that, might be just a typo and he meant + 0.5. I would anyways go for `histc()` for bining, clearer.

Comment: Yes, it's quite confusing what they did. The problem is that this code is actually internal to MATLAB itself. ;-) I am not sure it is a typo!

Comment: This is from MATLAB itself. Look at the extractHogFeature.m from the computer vision toolbox

Comment: @Learnaholic Sorry can't help, don't have that toolbox.